# Inflate a fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to do a ViewPager app and I want to inflate a class, I can only inflate an xml like this:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = null;
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dos, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tres, null);
            break;
    }
    ((ViewPager)container).addView(v, 0);

    return v;

}
```

But I want to something like this

```
 v = inflater.inflate(ListaFragment(), null);
```

And this it would be my ListaFragment activity

```
package com.germankatz.etacerfragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListaFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dos,
    container, false);

    TextView Numero = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Numero.setText("Funciono!!!!");

    return v;
   }
}
```

I didn't find something like this so that is why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I figure it out how to do it

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

/**
 *  Esto sirve para que ande el click y llevar a tal pagina ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem (1, true); que aparece en
 *  un onclicklistener de cada fragment
 */
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}

/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment b = null;

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            b = new ListaFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            b = new MainFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            b = new nextColeFragment();
            break;
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` you should `extends` one of the `PagerAdapter` classes (i.e. `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdatper`). Here the section in the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) where they show how to implement a `ViewPager` with `Fragments`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter for your viewpager that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) is the link that might help you.